# Show result from multiple InputBoxes in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remember how to create a Macros Button that will ask 2 or more questions and display them Show result from multiple InputBoxes in a single cell, any advice?

```
Sub Button5_Click()
    Dim response As String
    Range("B20").Value = InputBox("Please Include Name", "Name") 
    Range("B20").Value = InputBox("What is your favorite color", "Favorite Color")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combing the two results by doing

```
Sub Button5_Click()
   Range("B20").Value = InputBox("Please Include Name", "Name") 
   Range("B20").Value = Range("B20").Value & “, “ & InputBox("What is your favorite color", "Favorite Color")
End Sub
```

Or

```
Sub Button5_Click()
   [B20] = InputBox("Please Include Name", "Name") _ 
            & “, “ & InputBox("What is your favorite color", "Favorite Color")
End Sub
```

Another way would be to use variables.

```
Sub Button5_Click()
    dim ans1 as string, ans2 as string
    ans1 = InputBox("Please Include Name", "Name")
    ans2 = InputBox("What is your favorite color", "Favorite Color")
    [B20] = ans1 & " - " & ans2
End Sub
```

Comment: I thank you so much for your assistance but that is giving an error

Comment: Syntax ... I keep getting either one or the other every time I try to combine ... this is where I am having trouble

Comment: I edited the second option to the correct syntax (on mobile so untested) and added a third method which should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the data written from the first question in `B20` is overwritten by the data, written from the second question.

Usually the best idea is to make the code as simple as you can and then to make it readable:

```
Sub Button5_Click()

    Dim responseA As String
    Dim responseB As String
    
    responseA = InputBox("Please Include Name", "Name") 
    responseB = InputBox("What is your favorite color", "Favorite Color")
    Range("B20").Value = responseA & " ," &responseB

End Sub
```